# How to check if my ext4 mount is dirsync or not?

Tags: linux

I have several disk that format as ext4 and mount to several folders. I need to check if they are mount with dirsync option or not. How to do that? How to view the current mount option of my mount? I tried mount -v but I don't see the dirsync option in there.
Here is the response from mount -v

```
/dev/sda1 /data/sda1  ext4 inode_readahead_blks=128,data=writeback,noatime,nodev,nobarrier 1 2
/dev/sdb1 /data/sdb1  ext4 inode_readahead_blks=128,data=writeback,noatime,nodev,nobarrier 1 2
/dev/sdc1 /data/sdc1  ext4 inode_readahead_blks=128,data=writeback,noatime,nodev,nobarrier 1 2
```

I am using Centos 6

Thanks

Comment: Strange, for me on ubuntu when I mount an usb key with dirsync option I have the dirsync value in mount -v : /dev/sdb4 on /media/cle type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,dirsync,allow_other,blksize=4096)

Comment: Well, if mount -v doesn't show dirsync, it's not mounted with dirsync.

Comment: So what is the mount option it currently has?